# Прерывание цикла for с помощью break это плоxo?

Tags: java

И снова я со своей книгой "Для про". Почему в цикле `for` не рекомендуется прерывание с помощью `break`? Как же тогда это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно цитату из книги?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: how bad can it be? https://xkcd.com/292/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне этот совет кажется достаточно странным.

Представьте себе, что вы можете определить условие выхода только после какой-то работы. Например:

```
for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    File file = getFile(paths[i]);
    FileType ft = parseType(file);
    if (badTypes.contains(ft)) {
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Этот код говорит сам за себя: если мы нашли плохой тип файла, обработку завершаем.

Другие методы, например, присваивание специального значения переменной цикла или проверка специального флага «а не нужно ли нам завершить обработку вотпрямща», кажутся мне искусственными, костыльными путями сказать, что вы хотите просто завершить обработку в той точке, где стоит `break`.

В хорошем языке вы пишете то, что думаете, а не пытаетесь сказать это хитрыми косвенными методами.

Так что совет не использовать `break` я оставлю на совести автора книги. Этот совет мне кажется вредным.

---

Другое дело, что не стоит использовать `break` бесконтрольно, нужно всё время заботиться о читаемости кода. Иначе из полезного инструмента он превратится во вредный.

---

Дополнительно по теме: [Donald Knuth, *Structured Programming With Go To Statements*](http://wiki.c2.com/?StructuredProgrammingWithGoToStatements).

Comment: Почему-то ваши ответы сразу отодвигают другие :) Спасибо, тоже так думаю

Comment: @СергейГрушин: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Вместо цикла for в таких случаях, как в примере, логичнее использовать циклы while/do, как мне кажется

Comment: @pavlofff: Не вполне понимаю, почему. Мне казалось, если нужно перебирать индексы, то лучше не эмулировать цикл `for` через `while`, а прямо писать `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в книге имелось ввиду то, что не следует использовать прерывание цикла `for` с помощью `break` в **нормальных** ситуациях, так как естественное условие выхода из цикла `for` задается непосредственно при объявлении цикла.

А при возникновении каких-то **исключительных** ситуаций, когда из цикла необходимо выйти раньше, чем было задумано изначально, использование `break` вполне нормально и оправдано.

Comment: Скорее всего да, в книге говорится про то что надо не `break` а вызывать а, например, менять состояние пемеренной на что-то, а во втором аргументе проверять на дефолт. Если не дефолт значит все, хватит, нефиг итерировать

Comment: При возникновении исключительных ситуаций стоит бросать исключения :)

Answer (score -2):

Почему плохо goto? Эдсгер Дейкстра, в свое время очень хорошо [написал про это](http://hosting.vspu.ac.ru/~chul/dijkstra/goto/goto.htm)

break плох примерно по тем же причинам. Он нарушает execution flow. Не так фатально как goto, но все же.

Comment: Но здесь же имеется ввиду `break` именно в контексте цикла `for`. Далее по тексту для `while` он используется.

Comment: @post_zeew цикл `for(i=0;i<N;I++);`, если по канону, должен выполниться ровно `N` раз. Оператор `break` вносит неопределенность, что катастрофически ухудшает читаемость и понимаемость кода.

Comment: `goto`? Он может и хорош при вложенных циклах, когда надо остановить, например, первый из третьего. Но `break` то чем плох?

Comment: Вообще бред. Какая неопределенность? `break` нужен и лично у меня сразу при его виде мысля "выходим". И я уже не смотрю на `N` я смотрю что дальше. Если так все операторы об#ерать  то не получится норм кодить. Если мне надо сделать нечто долгое, но при выполнении условия, выйти, то что? Пускай оп. память закакается? `break` это полезный оператор

Comment: @СергейГрушин так. Стоп. Вы считаете `goto` хорошим оператором? У меня для вас плохие новости... Прочитайте статью Дейкстры, на которую я дал ссылку. Все же "икона" программирования как никак.

Comment: Как раз у меня очень плохое понятие о нем, я не был уверен, просто он входит в ключевые слова и я не мог поверить, что он нигде не используется. Я уже давно везде читал что он плох. Только вот не знал почему, сейчас прочитаю

Comment: @СергейГрушин у вас очень большой провал в теории. Это не в обиду, я и сам не то, чтоб все знаю. Почитайте про сложность алгоритмов, как она вычисляется. Это вам сильно поможет и на многое откроет глаза.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, В Java `goto` действительно является ключевым словом, но оно просто зарезервировано и не используется.

Comment: @СергейГрушин про сложность алгоритмов - это я немного ошибся. В данном контексте имеет смысл изучить такую штуку, как https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C